# I am not able to understand the working of bubble sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am really not able to understand how the bubble sort algorithm works. I am newbie to algorithms.

Comment: This is way too broad. What understanding do you have? What specifically don't you understand? Have you done any research? Visualizations of sorting algorithm returns fairly easy to find.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks, I didn't know of visualizations.

Comment: there are even hilarious youtube videos with some balkan people dancing & swapping themselves.

Comment: The way I learned to understand these things is to get a deck of cards and lay out 5 or 10 of them. Then manually go through the steps described. Having a physical model gives you one more "hook" on which to hang understanding. Even after almost 40 years of programming, I fall back on this (or similar) trick when I'm trying to understand a problem and its solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bubble sort simply swaps two elements directly comparing them without any advanced programming technique.It works in O(n^2) time that is it will take n^2 amount of proportional time where n is number of elements.

You should have done a some amount of effort as this is available in great visualization here https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting?slide=1.
This will definitely clarify the concept.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I got it.